# Proper way to update Aspnetboilerplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

What is the proper way for upgrade ASPNetBoilerplate template. my project initiation is with version 2.3.0 and for now we want to upgrade to version 3.0.0 . what is Step to step for upgrading project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are no strict rules to follow to update, But you can follow the below steps.

1. Download the latest template the same way you did in step 1 before.
2. Checkout the Framework-Master branch. The only thing here is just
       the raw framework files that I downloaded in step 1 of the previous steps.
3. Delete all the files from the previous framework check-in.
           You don't know if a file is removed or added to the new download so deleting and copying a fresh set over solves that.
4. Copy over the newly downloaded files.
5. Commit the changes. Now, the only thing in Framework-Master is the
   new download.
6. Checkout master.
7. Here you can optionally create a merge branch if you like or you can
   use master. I generally create a new branch. so I would git checkout
   -b "NewFrameworkVersion1_13" or something like that. This may only work in GIT. Say in TFS, I think you can only merge into a branch that you are branched from.
8. Merge Framework-Master into either Master or the new branch you
   created. NEVER MERGE TO FRAMEWORK-MASTER. That branch is just for
   the downloaded code ONLY.

Comment: plus read the release notes https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/releases

Comment: Thanks @AlperEbicoglu

Comment: Update with visual studio 15.3 has a lot of trouble, but updated with vs 15.5.6 @aaron

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to do this correctly is by analysing all the commits on Github for the release you aim and apply them manually on your project ([like this page](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/compare/v3.4.0...master) : tab "Files").

It's certainly fastidious but if you do it carefully, it works 100%. I do this for every releases of the module-zero-core-template for some times now. It's easier to do this for every releases than skipping several releases.