# How to upgrade aspnetboilerplate application. Abp 3.5.0 to Abp 6.0

Tags: .net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I have aspnetboilerplate application with abp 3.5.0 and .netcore2.0. How i can safely upgrade to abp 6.0 and .net 5.0.

Please also suggest which options is good moving towards .netcore 3.1 or .net 5.0. My application is under development.

Answer (score 0):

At the first, you need to know how to migrate from **ASP.Net Core 2.0** to **higher versions**. So follow the link [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.0 to x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/20_21?view=aspnetcore-6.0). On the left of the page, you can find how to migrate to different versions.

Then, review the [ASP.NET Boilerplate Documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/20_21?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to find what is changed and how the highest version works.

This link might be helpful: [Proper way to update Aspnetboilerplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401923/proper-way-to-update-aspnetboilerplate)

There is no straight way and you will be faced with some challenges.